# reCaptcha styling is broken

Tags: php, wordpress, stylesheet, recaptcha

I implemented reCaptcha into the following website. I used recaptchalib.php from Google Code and did not change anything in the PHP file.

However, the result reCaptcha in my website seems to broke. The buttons have weird white space above them. It works just fine, but it is not pretty :(

Here is the website that has problem:
http://### (removed)

Here is the code that I used to echo reCaptcha form

```
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "XXXXXXXXXXX"; // you got this from the signup page
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
```

Best regards

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same problem on all the websites I used reCaptcha. The CSS was somehow distorted. But I discovered that it was my line-height in the body tag. I believe you have the same problem too. Just use this css in your style sheet.

```
#recaptcha_area, #recaptcha_table { line-height: 0!important;}
```

Comment: Should be in the default css for recaptcha! Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work if in the case the recaptcha is inside Twitter Bootstrap Accordion. Wired enough, I can't find whats messed.

Comment: Well, I had the same issue. It looks fine now, But there is still a `Privacy & Terms` link over the captcha text field. Any solution ?

Answer (score 15):

Just recently added Re-Captcha (05/2014), and the following css snippets work for me.

```
   .recaptchatable, #recaptcha_area tr, #recaptcha_area td, #recaptcha_area th {
        line-height: 0 !important;
   }
   #recaptcha_area input {
        height: auto;
        display: inline;
   }
```

Comment: I tried other's solution and none worked by this solution. The date added Aug 26, 2015. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I had to reset the `display` and height properties of the `input` widget:

```
#recaptcha_area input {
    height: auto;
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me !!

```
#recaptcha_area input {
       height:auto;
       display: inline;
   }
#recaptcha_area * {
  line-height:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```
.recaptchatable, #recaptcha_area tr, #recaptcha_area td, #recaptcha_area th{
    line-height: 0 !important;
 }
#recaptcha_area input {
    height: auto;
    display: inline;
```

}

to customize it more
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/customization?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me

```
#recaptcha_table { 
    table-layout: auto;
}
```